# ThemeProvider: "theme' props is required - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run my app on an android emulator I got this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

App.js:

```js
import { StatusBar as ExpoStatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";

import { theme } from "./src/infrastructure/theme";
import { RestaurantsScreen } from "./src/features/restaurants/screens/restaurants.screen";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RestaurantsScreen />
      </ThemeProvider>
      <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
    </>
  );
}
```

restaurant-info-card.component.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";

const RestaurantCard = styled(Card)`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const RestaurantCardCover = styled(Card.Cover)`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
`;

const Title = styled(Text)`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ui.primary};
`;

export const RestaurantInfoCard = ({ restaurant = {} }) => {
  const {
    name = "Some Restaurant",
    icon,
    photos = [
      "https://www.foodiesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/top-view-for-box-of-2-burgers-home-made-600x899.jpg",
    ],
    address = "100 some random street",
    isOpenNow = true,
    rating = 4,
    isClosedTemporarily,
  } = restaurant;

  return (
    <RestaurantCard elevation={5}>
      <RestaurantCardCover key={name} source={{ uri: photos[0] }} />
      <Title>{name}</Title>
    </RestaurantCard>
  );
};
```

```js
restaurant.screen.js

import React from "react";
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { StatusBar, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

import { RestaurantInfoCard } from "../components/restaurant-info-card.component";

const SafeArea = styled(SafeAreaView)`
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: ${StatusBar.currentHeight}px;
`;

const SearchContainer = styled.View`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

const RestaurantListContainer = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

export const RestaurantsScreen = () => (
  <SafeArea>
    <SearchContainer>
      <Searchbar />
    </SearchContainer>
    <RestaurantListContainer>
      <RestaurantInfoCard />
    </RestaurantListContainer>
  </SafeArea>
);
```

can someone help me please this error is stuck with me. I learn this from a course on Udemy and this keeps me in the lecture and can't go further.

This is just some random text to make it meet the requirement:
`af;ljadslfjiemlcjialkjlfjaiel fa;slkdfjiem fal;skjfioelajd fl;akjdf kljepidf asdl;fmas dk;fljei fla;dfkjal;sdfjla;sdjf;al meiladlj;alksdjfal;ksdjfa;dfadf;j ad;lfja df lajdfa;ldfkj adl;fkj adl;fjka dls;fjkeimlcjal;mcljeio3em3ljlk3jlkj3lkj3lkji3mm3jdj`

Comment: It looks like an issue with the theme that you've passed to `ThemeProvider`. What does `./src/infrastructure/theme`  look like?

Comment: colors.js:`export const colors = {
  brand: {
    primary: "#2182BD",
    secondary: "#5282BD",
    muted: "#C6DAF7",
  },
  ui: {
    primary: "#262626",
    secondary: "#757575",
    tertiary: "#F1F1F1",
    quaternary: "#FFFFFF",
    disabled: "#DEDEDE",
    error: "#D0421B",
    success: "#138000",
  },
  bg: {
    primary: "#FFFFFF",
    secondary: "#F1F1F1",
  },
  text: {
    primary: "#262626",
    secondary: "#757575",
    disabled: "#9C9C9C",
    inverse: "#FFFFFF",
    error: "#D0421B",
    success: "#138000",
  },
};`

Comment: sorry i just enter it randomly :):
fonts.js:
`export const fonts = {
  body: "Oswald_400Regular",
  heading: "Lato_400Regular",
  monospace: "Oswald_400Regular",
};

export const fontWeights = {
  regular: 400,
  medium: 500,
  bold: 700,
};

export const fontSizes = {
  caption: "12px",
  button: "14px",
  body: "16px",
  title: "20px",
  h5: "24px",
  h4: "34px",
  h3: "45px",
  h2: "56px",
  h1: "112px",
};`

Comment: sizes.js: 
`export const sizes = ["8px", "16px", "32px", "64px", "128px"];`
spacing.js: `export const lineHeights = {
  title: "28px",
  copy: "20px",
};

export const space = ["0px", "4px", "8px", "16px", "32px", "64px"];`
index.js: `import { colors } from "./colors";
import { space, lineHeights } from "./spacing";
import { sizes } from "./sizes";
import { fonts, fontWeights, fontSizes } from "./fonts";

export const theme = {
  colors,
  space,
  lineHeights,
  sizes,
  fonts,
  fontSizes,
  fontWeights,
};`

Comment: spacing.js:
export const lineHeights = {
  title: "28px",
  copy: "20px",
};

export const space = ["0px", "4px", "8px", "16px", "32px", "64px"];`
`

Comment: it looks like you should be importing theme from `size.js`

Comment: I don't understand too much?

Comment: Well the error says that the theme provider must have a theme prop, which means that your import of theme is undefined

Comment: How to fix that like what do I need to change in my code? Can you help me, please? I am completely a beginner so... yeah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251165/discussion-between-phantomspooks-and-truong-hao-nhien).

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was that

```
import { theme } from "./src/infrastructure/theme";
```

Should have been

```
import { theme } from "./src/infrastructure/theme/index";
```

In typescript if you try to import a folder it will by default look for the index file. Maybe with some babel config you could get regular javascript to do this, but I dont think it is supported out of the box. Next, you need to configure the index file:

```js
import colors from './colors';
import { fonts, fontSizes, fontWeights } from './fonts';
import sizes from './sizes';
import { lineHeights, space } from './spacing';
export const theme = {
  colors,
  space,
  lineHeights,
  sizes,
  fonts,
  fontSizes,
  fontWeights,
};
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/nTyoo1unNW)

Comment: I have got another error please help:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.theme.colors.bg')

Comment: i have posted the full error log in our chat dicussion:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251165/discussion-between-phantomspooks-and-truong-hao-nhien